# Compare two SQL tables and find the differences

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table that have more than 30 columns each. I need to compare the tables and find those rows that are

1. Are in one table, but not in the other
2. have most columns the same, but not all

I'm having difficulty getting this done. I've tried using a Union All to compare the two tables. With tables A and B I get all rows that

1. Are in A and not in B
2. Are in B and not in A
3. Are in both tables but don't have all columns exactly the same

I've used the `except` function of SQL and I can get all the rows from A that are not in B or all rows from B that are not in A.

I have an SP that does the `UNION ALL` based on [this](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/10/2737.aspx) Blog article. Then I've found where `Except` is used to get differences from two tables and have tried that. I am unable to accomplish my goal however. What I'm ultimately trying to do is that I have Data in A that needs to be updated/Deleted/Added to based on what is in table B. I want to be able to compare the 2 table and

1. Insert from B what is not already in A
2. Delete from A what is not in B
3. Update A with rows in B that are different from A in only a couple of columns

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT 3**

After speaking with my team here I have a 4 column match that I can make to identify which rows should be the same. It's the PONumber, POLineNumber, IMLineNumber and ProjectNumber (in that order) that I'll match on since I don't have a common ID.

**Edit**

There is no primary key that is in both tables. I should have added this at first, but didn't think of it till seeing the comments and answers below. I have to match everything based on the data in the rows and not on a particular key. I will get the tables data maps on here tomorrow.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
    insert into working.ComparedMaterialTrackingTables(TableName
            ,State
            ,ProjectNumber
            ,SubProjectNumber
            ,PONumber
            ,POLineNumber
            ,IMLineNumber
            ,CalloutDetails
            ,POStatus
            ,BlanketRelease
            ,PODateIssued
            ,DateNeeded
            ,POInvoiceStatus
            ,ItemCode
            ,ItemDesc
            ,QuantityOrdered
            ,QuantityReceived
            ,DateReceived
            ,RecordStatus
            ,ShipToLocation
            ,DeliverToLocation
            ,ReceiverId
            ,TraceNumber
            ,BOL
            ,PackSlipNumber
            ,POTotalAmount
            ,POLineAmount
            ,CostCode
            ,RequisitionId
            ,RequisitionLineNumber
            ,Vendor
            ,ExchangeName
            ,ProjectType
            ,COECurrentProjectStatus
            ,ReadyForService
            ,ScheduledShipDate
            ,MaterialComments
            ,SchedulerComments
            ,MaterialSpecialist)
exec spCompareTables @Table1='TestingTable', @Table2='working.MaterialTracking'
, @T1Columns='State,ProjectNumber,SubProjectNumber,PONumber,POLineNumber,IMLineNumber,CalloutDetails,POStatus,BlanketRelease,PODateIssued,DateNeeded
    ,POInvoiceStatus,ItemCode,ItemDesc,QuantityOrdered,QuantityReceived,DateReceived,RecordStatus,ShipToLocation,DeliverToLocation,ReceiverId
    ,TraceNumber,BOL,PackSlipNumber,POTotalAmount,POLineAmount,CostCode,RequisitionId,RequisitionLineNumber,Vendor,ExchangeName,ProjectType
    ,COECurrentProjectStatus,ReadyForService,ScheduledShipDate,MaterialComments,SchedulerComments,MaterialSpecialist'

begin tran  --commit    rollback
create table #MaterialID(ID int)
insert into #MaterialID(ID)
select tt.woid from working.MaterialTracking tt
join (select State
            ,ProjectNumber
            ,SubProjectNumber
            ,PONumber
            ,POLineNumber
            ,IMLineNumber
            ,CalloutDetails
            ,POStatus
            ,BlanketRelease
            ,PODateIssued
            ,DateNeeded
            ,POInvoiceStatus
            ,ItemCode
            ,ItemDesc
            ,QuantityOrdered
            ,QuantityReceived
            ,DateReceived
            ,RecordStatus
            ,ShipToLocation
            ,DeliverToLocation
            ,ReceiverId
            ,TraceNumber
            ,BOL
            ,PackSlipNumber
            ,POTotalAmount
            ,POLineAmount
            ,CostCode
            ,RequisitionId
            ,RequisitionLineNumber
            ,Vendor
            ,ExchangeName
            ,ProjectType
            ,COECurrentProjectStatus
            ,ReadyForService
            ,ScheduledShipDate
            ,MaterialComments
            ,SchedulerComments
            ,MaterialSpecialist
    from working.MaterialTracking
    Except
    select State
            ,ProjectNumber
            ,SubProjectNumber
            ,PONumber
            ,POLineNumber
            ,IMLineNumber
            ,CalloutDetails
            ,POStatus
            ,BlanketRelease
            ,PODateIssued
            ,DateNeeded
            ,POInvoiceStatus
            ,ItemCode
            ,ItemDesc
            ,QuantityOrdered
            ,QuantityReceived
            ,DateReceived
            ,RecordStatus
            ,ShipToLocation
            ,DeliverToLocation
            ,ReceiverId
            ,TraceNumber
            ,BOL
            ,PackSlipNumber
            ,POTotalAmount
            ,POLineAmount
            ,CostCode
            ,RequisitionId
            ,RequisitionLineNumber
            ,Vendor
            ,ExchangeName
            ,ProjectType
            ,COECurrentProjectStatus
            ,ReadyForService
            ,ScheduledShipDate
            ,MaterialComments
            ,SchedulerComments
            ,MaterialSpecialist
    from TestingTable) ctt on ctt.State = tt.State 
            and ctt.ProjectNumber = tt.ProjectNumber 
            and ctt.SubProjectNumber = tt.SubProjectNumber 
            and ctt.PONumber = tt.PONumber 
            and ctt.POLineNumber = tt.POLineNumber 
            and ctt.IMLineNumber = tt.IMLineNumber 
            and ctt.POStatus = tt.POStatus 
            and ctt.BlanketRelease = tt.BlanketRelease 
            and ctt.PODateIssued = tt.PODateIssued 
            and ctt.DateNeeded = tt.DateNeeded 
            and ctt.POInvoiceStatus = tt.POInvoiceStatus 
            and ctt.ItemCode = tt.ItemCode 
            and ctt.ItemDesc = tt.ItemDesc 
            and ctt.QuantityOrdered = tt.QuantityOrdered 
            and ctt.ShipToLocation = tt.ShipToLocation 
            and ctt.DeliverToLocation = tt.DeliverToLocation 
            and ctt.TraceNumber = tt.TraceNumber 
            and ctt.BOL = tt.BOL 
            and ctt.PackSlipNumber = tt.PackSlipNumber 
            and ctt.POTotalAmount = tt.POTotalAmount 
            and ctt.POLineAmount = tt.POLineAmount 
            and ctt.CostCode = tt.CostCode 
            and ctt.RequisitionId = tt.RequisitionId 
            and ctt.RequisitionLineNumber = tt.RequisitionLineNumber 
            and ctt.Vendor = tt.Vendor 
            and ctt.ExchangeName = tt.ExchangeName 
            and ctt.COECurrentProjectStatus = tt.COECurrentProjectStatus 
            and ctt.ReadyForService = tt.ReadyForService 
            and ctt.MaterialSpecialist = tt.MaterialSpecialist 
            and ctt.QuantityReceived = tt.QuantityReceived 
            and ctt.DateReceived = tt.DateReceived 
            and ctt.ReceiverId = tt.ReceiverId 
            and ctt.ScheduledShipDate = tt.ScheduledShipDate 
            and ctt.CalloutDetails = tt.CalloutDetails 
            and ctt.ProjectType = tt.ProjectType 
            and ctt.RecordStatus = tt.RecordStatus 
            and ctt.MaterialComments = tt.MaterialComments 
            and ctt.SchedulerComments = tt.SchedulerComments

insert into TestingTable (State
            ,ProjectNumber
            ,SubProjectNumber
            ,PONumber
            ,POLineNumber
            ,IMLineNumber
            ,CalloutDetails
            ,POStatus
            ,BlanketRelease
            ,PODateIssued
            ,DateNeeded
            ,POInvoiceStatus
            ,ItemCode
            ,ItemDesc
            ,QuantityOrdered
            ,QuantityReceived
            ,DateReceived
            ,RecordStatus
            ,ShipToLocation
            ,DeliverToLocation
            ,ReceiverId
            ,TraceNumber
            ,BOL
            ,PackSlipNumber
            ,POTotalAmount
            ,POLineAmount
            ,CostCode
            ,RequisitionId
            ,RequisitionLineNumber
            ,Vendor
            ,ExchangeName
            ,ProjectType
            ,COECurrentProjectStatus
            ,ReadyForService
            ,ScheduledShipDate
            ,MaterialComments
            ,SchedulerComments
            ,MaterialSpecialist)
select State
        ,ProjectNumber
        ,SubProjectNumber
        ,PONumber
        ,POLineNumber
        ,IMLineNumber
        ,CalloutDetails
        ,POStatus
        ,BlanketRelease
        ,PODateIssued
        ,DateNeeded
        ,POInvoiceStatus
        ,ItemCode
        ,ItemDesc
        ,QuantityOrdered
        ,QuantityReceived
        ,DateReceived
        ,RecordStatus
        ,ShipToLocation
        ,DeliverToLocation
        ,ReceiverId
        ,TraceNumber
        ,BOL
        ,PackSlipNumber
        ,POTotalAmount
        ,POLineAmount
        ,CostCode
        ,RequisitionId
        ,RequisitionLineNumber
        ,Vendor
        ,ExchangeName
        ,ProjectType
        ,COECurrentProjectStatus
        ,ReadyForService
        ,ScheduledShipDate
        ,MaterialComments
        ,SchedulerComments
        ,MaterialSpecialist
from working.MaterialTracking
Except
select State
        ,ProjectNumber
        ,SubProjectNumber
        ,PONumber
        ,POLineNumber
        ,IMLineNumber
        ,CalloutDetails
        ,POStatus
        ,BlanketRelease
        ,PODateIssued
        ,DateNeeded
        ,POInvoiceStatus
        ,ItemCode
        ,ItemDesc
        ,QuantityOrdered
        ,QuantityReceived
        ,DateReceived
        ,RecordStatus
        ,ShipToLocation
        ,DeliverToLocation
        ,ReceiverId
        ,TraceNumber
        ,BOL
        ,PackSlipNumber
        ,POTotalAmount
        ,POLineAmount
        ,CostCode
        ,RequisitionId
        ,RequisitionLineNumber
        ,Vendor
        ,ExchangeName
        ,ProjectType
        ,COECurrentProjectStatus
        ,ReadyForService
        ,ScheduledShipDate
        ,MaterialComments
        ,SchedulerComments
        ,MaterialSpecialist
from TestingTable

delete from working.MaterialTracking
from working.MaterialTracking mt
join #MaterialID mi on mi.ID = mt.WOID
```

**Edit 2**
Here's the table data for the working.MaterialTracking table:

```
TABLE_NAME          COLUMN_NAME             IS_NULLABLE DATA_TYPE
MaterialTracking    ID                      NO          uniqueidentifier
MaterialTracking    State                   YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    ProjectNumber           YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    SubProjectNumber        YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    PONumber                YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    POLineNumber            YES         int
MaterialTracking    IMLineNumber            YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    CalloutDetails          YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    POStatus                YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    BlanketRelease          YES         int
MaterialTracking    PODateIssued            YES         datetime
MaterialTracking    DateNeeded              YES         datetime
MaterialTracking    POInvoiceStatus         YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    ItemCode                YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    ItemDesc                YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    QuantityOrdered         YES         numeric
MaterialTracking    QuantityReceived        YES         numeric
MaterialTracking    DateReceived            YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    RecordStatus            YES         varchar
MaterialTracking    ShipToLocation          YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    DeliverToLocation       YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    ReceiverId              YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    TraceNumber             YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    BOL                     YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    PackSlipNumber          YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    POTotalAmount           YES         numeric
MaterialTracking    POLineAmount            YES         numeric
MaterialTracking    CostCode                YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    RequisitionId           YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    RequisitionLineNumber   YES         int
MaterialTracking    Vendor                  YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    ExchangeName            YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    ProjectType             YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    COECurrentProjectStatus YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    ReadyForService         YES         datetime
MaterialTracking    ScheduledShipDate       YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    MaterialComments        YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    SchedulerComments       YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    MaterialSpecialist      YES         nvarchar
MaterialTracking    woid                    NO          int
```

And here's the TestingTable:

```
TABLE_NAME      COLUMN_NAME             IS_NULLABLE DATA_TYPE
TestingTable    State                   YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    ProjectNumber           YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    SubProjectNumber        YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    PONumber                YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    POLineNumber            YES         int
TestingTable    IMLineNumber            YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    POStatus                YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    BlanketRelease          YES         int
TestingTable    PODateIssued            YES         datetime
TestingTable    DateNeeded              YES         datetime
TestingTable    POInvoiceStatus         YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    ItemCode                YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    ItemDesc                YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    QuantityOrdered         YES         numeric
TestingTable    ShipToLocation          YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    DeliverToLocation       YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    TraceNumber             YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    BOL                     YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    PackSlipNumber          YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    POTotalAmount           YES         numeric
TestingTable    POLineAmount            YES         numeric
TestingTable    CostCode                YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    RequisitionId           YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    RequisitionLineNumber   YES         int
TestingTable    Vendor                  YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    ExchangeName            YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    COECurrentProjectStatus YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    ReadyForService         YES         datetime
TestingTable    MaterialSpecialist      YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    QuantityReceived        YES         numeric
TestingTable    DateReceived            YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    ReceiverId              YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    ScheduledShipDate       YES         datetime
TestingTable    CalloutDetails          YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    ProjectType             YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    RecordStatus            YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    MaterialComments        YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    SchedulerComments       YES         nvarchar
TestingTable    ID                      YES         int
```

The ID for both columns is an identity that is created as the rows are added and is not dependent on each other. So trying to match based on the ID won't work. I'm not able to do a truncate and re-populate from B since there are people in the table working and locking rows. That's why I'm just updating, inserting and deleting rows not the whole table. I do want A to be exactly B I just can't truncate and replace.

**EDIT 4**

Here is the `merge` script that I created and ran. It seems to have worked, but it deleted each row and then inserted each row. I don't know if that is what is supposed to happen or if I set it up wrong?

```
    begin tran  --commit    rollback
merge into pmdb.MaterialTracking as target
using (select State,ProjectNumber,SubProjectNumber,PONumber,POLineNumber,IMLineNumber,CalloutDetails,POStatus,BlanketRelease,PODateIssued,DateNeeded
        ,POInvoiceStatus,ItemCode,ItemDesc,QuantityOrdered,QuantityReceived,DateReceived,RecordStatus,ShipToLocation,DeliverToLocation,ReceiverId
        ,TraceNumber,BOL,PackSlipNumber,POTotalAmount,POLineAmount,CostCode,RequisitionId,RequisitionLineNumber,Vendor,ExchangeName,ProjectType
        ,COECurrentProjectStatus,ReadyForService,ScheduledShipDate,MaterialComments,SchedulerComments,MaterialSpecialist from working.MaterialTracking) as source 
    on (target.PONumber = source.PONumber and target.POLineNumber = source.POLineNumber and target.IMLineNumber = source.IMLineNumber 
            and target.ProjectNumber = source.ProjectNumber)
when matched and (ISNULL(Target.State,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.State,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.SubProjectNumber,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.SubProjectNumber,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.POStatus,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.POStatus,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.BlanketRelease,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.BlanketRelease,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.PODateIssued,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.PODateIssued,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.DateNeeded,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.DateNeeded,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.POInvoiceStatus,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.POInvoiceStatus,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.ItemCode,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.ItemCode,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.ItemDesc,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.ItemDesc,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.QuantityOrdered,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.QuantityOrdered,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.ShipToLocation,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.ShipToLocation,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.DeliverToLocation,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.DeliverToLocation,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.TraceNumber,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.TraceNumber,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.BOL,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.BOL,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.PackSlipNumber,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.PackSlipNumber,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.POTotalAmount,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.POTotalAmount,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.POLineAmount,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.POLineAmount,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.CostCode,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.CostCode,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.RequisitionId,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.RequisitionId,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.RequisitionLineNumber,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.RequisitionLineNumber,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.Vendor,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.Vendor,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.ExchangeName,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.ExchangeName,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.COECurrentProjectStatus,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.COECurrentProjectStatus,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.ReadyForService,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.ReadyForService,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.MaterialSpecialist,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.MaterialSpecialist,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.QuantityReceived,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.QuantityReceived,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.DateReceived,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.DateReceived,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.ReceiverId,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.ReceiverId,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.ScheduledShipDate,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.ScheduledShipDate,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.CalloutDetails,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.CalloutDetails,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.ProjectType,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.ProjectType,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.RecordStatus,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.RecordStatus,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.MaterialComments,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.MaterialComments,'NULL') OR
                    ISNULL(Target.SchedulerComments,'NULL') <> ISNULL(Source.SchedulerComments,'NULL'))
    then update
    set State = Source.State,
        SubProjectNumber = Source.SubProjectNumber,
        POStatus = Source.POStatus,
        BlanketRelease = Source.BlanketRelease,
        PODateIssued = Source.PODateIssued,
        DateNeeded = Source.DateNeeded,
        POInvoiceStatus = Source.POInvoiceStatus,
        ItemCode = Source.ItemCode,
        ItemDesc = Source.ItemDesc,
        QuantityOrdered = Source.QuantityOrdered,
        ShipToLocation = Source.ShipToLocation,
        DeliverToLocation = Source.DeliverToLocation,
        TraceNumber = Source.TraceNumber,
        BOL = Source.BOL,
        PackSlipNumber = Source.PackSlipNumber,
        POTotalAmount = Source.POTotalAmount,
        POLineAmount = Source.POLineAmount,
        CostCode = Source.CostCode,
        RequisitionId = Source.RequisitionId,
        RequisitionLineNumber = Source.RequisitionLineNumber,
        Vendor = Source.Vendor,
        ExchangeName = Source.ExchangeName,
        COECurrentProjectStatus = Source.COECurrentProjectStatus,
        ReadyForService = Source.ReadyForService,
        MaterialSpecialist = Source.MaterialSpecialist,
        QuantityReceived = Source.QuantityReceived,
        DateReceived = Source.DateReceived,
        ReceiverId = Source.ReceiverId,
        ScheduledShipDate = Source.ScheduledShipDate,
        CalloutDetails = Source.CalloutDetails,
        ProjectType = Source.ProjectType,
        RecordStatus = Source.RecordStatus,
        MaterialComments = Source.MaterialComments,
        SchedulerComments = Source.SchedulerComments

when not matched by target then
insert (State,ProjectNumber,SubProjectNumber,PONumber,POLineNumber,IMLineNumber,CalloutDetails,POStatus,BlanketRelease,PODateIssued,DateNeeded
        ,POInvoiceStatus,ItemCode,ItemDesc,QuantityOrdered,QuantityReceived,DateReceived,RecordStatus,ShipToLocation,DeliverToLocation,ReceiverId
        ,TraceNumber,BOL,PackSlipNumber,POTotalAmount,POLineAmount,CostCode,RequisitionId,RequisitionLineNumber,Vendor,ExchangeName,ProjectType
        ,COECurrentProjectStatus,ReadyForService,ScheduledShipDate,MaterialComments,SchedulerComments,MaterialSpecialist)
values (State,ProjectNumber,SubProjectNumber,PONumber,POLineNumber,IMLineNumber,CalloutDetails,POStatus,BlanketRelease,PODateIssued,DateNeeded
        ,POInvoiceStatus,ItemCode,ItemDesc,QuantityOrdered,QuantityReceived,DateReceived,RecordStatus,ShipToLocation,DeliverToLocation,ReceiverId
        ,TraceNumber,BOL,PackSlipNumber,POTotalAmount,POLineAmount,CostCode,RequisitionId,RequisitionLineNumber,Vendor,ExchangeName,ProjectType
        ,COECurrentProjectStatus,ReadyForService,ScheduledShipDate,MaterialComments,SchedulerComments,MaterialSpecialist)

when not matched by source then
delete

output $action, Inserted.*,Deleted.*;
/*
select * from pmdb.MaterialTracking
*/
```

Comment: That is exactly what `MERGE` statement does. Update `MATCHED`, delete `NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE`, insert `NOT MATCHED BY TARGET`.

Comment: I would also recommend formatting your sql. This wall of text is impossible to read. White space is your friend, don't be scared to use it liberally.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I used to use merge and stopped after reading up on the issues with it here is a link for you https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: @Matt `MERGE` works fine if you use the `HOLDLOCK` locking hint.  The primary issue is one of concurrency.

Comment: It's important that you provide your table definition here.  What's the primary key?  Which fields are nullable?  If any of them are, then your SP is going to fail because none of your comparisons handle null values correctly.

Comment: @BaconBits I will look into `Merge`, but if it really has all these problems is it safe to use? Also I can handle the `NULL` values all columns except 1 or 2 are `NULLABLE`

Comment: Normally I'd suggest MERGE, but the fact that you have no keys and different table definitions makes it feel like a bad idea to me.  MERGE works well when the tables are exactly the same and share a common key.  I'd be much less willing to do it otherwise.

Comment: @BaconBits Only the ID columns are different and I'll not be worrying about matching or inserting them. All the other columns are the same. There isn't a common primary key though. I did try the `Merge` and it seems to have worked, but it looks like it deleted every line and then inserted every line. I'm not sure that is what it's supposed to do or not. I'll be adding an edit above with the new code.

Comment: Without some shared key, there's no way to do this without just deleting and inserting.  Update is impossible, because how do you match records?  No key.  No record matching.  No update.

Comment: Is it safe to use merge? yes, if you pay attention to certain concurrency and things from that article which in a simplified environment are probably not a problem..  The insert, update, delete depending on isolation level can still lead to issues if you don't wait for records to commit from moving from one operation to another, which is many times why I use a temp table to process/track progress and/or use the OUTPUT clause. @BaconBits HOLDLOCK will block other processes from modifying (I,U,D) the table until you are finished but still allow reads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, I'd suggest using a MERGE statement because it's pretty easy to set up, but it's not going to work well here because of the lack of a key.  Without an index, this is likely to take a really long time, but with 38 columns, it's also going to be a fairly large index.  Still, I'd suggest creating a NONCLUSTERED index if you run into significant performance problems.

What you'll want to do is DELETE first and then INSERT, do it in a single transaction, and handle NULLs on the join.  Normally you do a DELETE first because you don't want to run into key violations.  There's no purpose in trying to do UPDATE here.  Without a shared key, it's *impossible* to tell when to update except for the trivial case when everything already matches.

All these methods will run into problems if you have records in MaterialTracking where all 38 fields are duplicated, or where all 38 fields are NULL.  It's not a good idea to not have a shared key here.  Even adding a field to TestTable just to store the primary key from MaterialTracking would be preferable.

I would do it like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

;WITH TestTable_ToDelete AS (
    SELECT tt.State,tt.ProjectNumber,tt.SubProjectNumber,tt.PONumber,tt.POLineNumber,tt.IMLineNumber,tt.POStatus,tt.BlanketRelease,tt.PODateIssued,tt.DateNeeded,
        tt.POInvoiceStatus,tt.ItemCode,tt.ItemDesc,tt.QuantityOrdered,tt.ShipToLocation,tt.DeliverToLocation,tt.TraceNumber,tt.BOL,tt.PackSlipNumber,tt.POTotalAmount,
        tt.POLineAmount,tt.CostCode,tt.RequisitionId,tt.RequisitionLineNumber,tt.Vendor,tt.ExchangeName,tt.COECurrentProjectStatus,tt.ReadyForService,tt.MaterialSpecialist,
        tt.QuantityReceived,tt.DateReceived,tt.ReceiverId,tt.ScheduledShipDate,tt.CalloutDetails,tt.ProjectType,tt.RecordStatus,tt.MaterialComments,tt.SchedulerComments
    FROM TestTable tt

    EXCEPT

    SELECT mt.State,mt.ProjectNumber,mt.SubProjectNumber,mt.PONumber,mt.POLineNumber,mt.IMLineNumber,mt.POStatus,mt.BlanketRelease,mt.PODateIssued,mt.DateNeeded,
        mt.POInvoiceStatus,mt.ItemCode,mt.ItemDesc,mt.QuantityOrdered,mt.ShipToLocation,mt.DeliverToLocation,mt.TraceNumber,mt.BOL,mt.PackSlipNumber,mt.POTotalAmount,
        mt.POLineAmount,mt.CostCode,mt.RequisitionId,mt.RequisitionLineNumber,mt.Vendor,mt.ExchangeName,mt.COECurrentProjectStatus,mt.ReadyForService,mt.MaterialSpecialist,
        mt.QuantityReceived,mt.DateReceived,mt.ReceiverId,mt.ScheduledShipDate,mt.CalloutDetails,mt.ProjectType,mt.RecordStatus,mt.MaterialComments,mt.SchedulerComments
    FROM MaterialTracking mt
)
DELETE FROM TestTable_ToDelete;

;WITH TestTable_ToInsert (
    SELECT mt.State,mt.ProjectNumber,mt.SubProjectNumber,mt.PONumber,mt.POLineNumber,mt.IMLineNumber,mt.POStatus,mt.BlanketRelease,mt.PODateIssued,mt.DateNeeded,
        mt.POInvoiceStatus,mt.ItemCode,mt.ItemDesc,mt.QuantityOrdered,mt.ShipToLocation,mt.DeliverToLocation,mt.TraceNumber,mt.BOL,mt.PackSlipNumber,mt.POTotalAmount,
        mt.POLineAmount,mt.CostCode,mt.RequisitionId,mt.RequisitionLineNumber,mt.Vendor,mt.ExchangeName,mt.COECurrentProjectStatus,mt.ReadyForService,mt.MaterialSpecialist,
        mt.QuantityReceived,mt.DateReceived,mt.ReceiverId,mt.ScheduledShipDate,mt.CalloutDetails,mt.ProjectType,mt.RecordStatus,mt.MaterialComments,mt.SchedulerComments
    FROM MaterialTracking mt

    EXCEPT

    SELECT tt.State,tt.ProjectNumber,tt.SubProjectNumber,tt.PONumber,tt.POLineNumber,tt.IMLineNumber,tt.POStatus,tt.BlanketRelease,tt.PODateIssued,tt.DateNeeded,
        tt.POInvoiceStatus,tt.ItemCode,tt.ItemDesc,tt.QuantityOrdered,tt.ShipToLocation,tt.DeliverToLocation,tt.TraceNumber,tt.BOL,tt.PackSlipNumber,tt.POTotalAmount,
        tt.POLineAmount,tt.CostCode,tt.RequisitionId,tt.RequisitionLineNumber,tt.Vendor,tt.ExchangeName,tt.COECurrentProjectStatus,tt.ReadyForService,tt.MaterialSpecialist,
        tt.QuantityReceived,tt.DateReceived,tt.ReceiverId,tt.ScheduledShipDate,tt.CalloutDetails,tt.ProjectType,tt.RecordStatus,tt.MaterialComments,tt.SchedulerComments
    FROM TestTable tt
)
INSERT INTO TestTable (State,ProjectNumber,SubProjectNumber,PONumber,POLineNumber,IMLineNumber,POStatus,BlanketRelease,PODateIssued,DateNeeded,
    POInvoiceStatus,ItemCode,ItemDesc,QuantityOrdered,ShipToLocation,DeliverToLocation,TraceNumber,BOL,PackSlipNumber,POTotalAmount,
    POLineAmount,CostCode,RequisitionId,RequisitionLineNumber,Vendor,ExchangeName,COECurrentProjectStatus,ReadyForService,MaterialSpecialist,
    QuantityReceived,DateReceived,ReceiverId,ScheduledShipDate,CalloutDetails,ProjectType,RecordStatus,MaterialComments,SchedulerComments)
SELECT State,ProjectNumber,SubProjectNumber,PONumber,POLineNumber,IMLineNumber,POStatus,BlanketRelease,PODateIssued,DateNeeded,
    POInvoiceStatus,ItemCode,ItemDesc,QuantityOrdered,ShipToLocation,DeliverToLocation,TraceNumber,BOL,PackSlipNumber,POTotalAmount,
    POLineAmount,CostCode,RequisitionId,RequisitionLineNumber,Vendor,ExchangeName,COECurrentProjectStatus,ReadyForService,MaterialSpecialist,
    QuantityReceived,DateReceived,ReceiverId,ScheduledShipDate,CalloutDetails,ProjectType,RecordStatus,MaterialComments,SchedulerComments
FROM TestTable_ToInsert;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

The alternative is to do something like this, but it will probably be just as slow.  Notice how gross the JOIN conditions get because the fields are nullable.  There's no way around this unless you have keys.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION MAIN;

DELETE tt
FROM TestingTable tt
LEFT JOIN MaterialTracking mt
    ON  (mt.State                   = tt.State                   OR (mt.State                   IS NULL AND tt.State                   IS NULL))
    AND (mt.ProjectNumber           = tt.ProjectNumber           OR (mt.ProjectNumber           IS NULL AND tt.ProjectNumber           IS NULL))
    AND (mt.SubProjectNumber        = tt.SubProjectNumber        OR (mt.SubProjectNumber        IS NULL AND tt.SubProjectNumber        IS NULL))
    AND (mt.PONumber                = tt.PONumber                OR (mt.PONumber                IS NULL AND tt.PONumber                IS NULL))
    AND (mt.POLineNumber            = tt.POLineNumber            OR (mt.POLineNumber            IS NULL AND tt.POLineNumber            IS NULL))
    AND (mt.IMLineNumber            = tt.IMLineNumber            OR (mt.IMLineNumber            IS NULL AND tt.IMLineNumber            IS NULL))
    AND (mt.POStatus                = tt.POStatus                OR (mt.POStatus                IS NULL AND tt.POStatus                IS NULL))
    AND (mt.BlanketRelease          = tt.BlanketRelease          OR (mt.BlanketRelease          IS NULL AND tt.BlanketRelease          IS NULL))
    AND (mt.PODateIssued            = tt.PODateIssued            OR (mt.PODateIssued            IS NULL AND tt.PODateIssued            IS NULL))
    AND (mt.DateNeeded              = tt.DateNeeded              OR (mt.DateNeeded              IS NULL AND tt.DateNeeded              IS NULL))
    AND (mt.POInvoiceStatus         = tt.POInvoiceStatus         OR (mt.POInvoiceStatus         IS NULL AND tt.POInvoiceStatus         IS NULL))
    AND (mt.ItemCode                = tt.ItemCode                OR (mt.ItemCode                IS NULL AND tt.ItemCode                IS NULL))
    AND (mt.ItemDesc                = tt.ItemDesc                OR (mt.ItemDesc                IS NULL AND tt.ItemDesc                IS NULL))
    AND (mt.QuantityOrdered         = tt.QuantityOrdered         OR (mt.QuantityOrdered         IS NULL AND tt.QuantityOrdered         IS NULL))
    AND (mt.ShipToLocation          = tt.ShipToLocation          OR (mt.ShipToLocation          IS NULL AND tt.ShipToLocation          IS NULL))
    AND (mt.DeliverToLocation       = tt.DeliverToLocation       OR (mt.DeliverToLocation       IS NULL AND tt.DeliverToLocation       IS NULL))
    AND (mt.TraceNumber             = tt.TraceNumber             OR (mt.TraceNumber             IS NULL AND tt.TraceNumber             IS NULL))
    AND (mt.BOL                     = tt.BOL                     OR (mt.BOL                     IS NULL AND tt.BOL                     IS NULL))
    AND (mt.PackSlipNumber          = tt.PackSlipNumber          OR (mt.PackSlipNumber          IS NULL AND tt.PackSlipNumber          IS NULL))
    AND (mt.POTotalAmount           = tt.POTotalAmount           OR (mt.POTotalAmount           IS NULL AND tt.POTotalAmount           IS NULL))
    AND (mt.POLineAmount            = tt.POLineAmount            OR (mt.POLineAmount            IS NULL AND tt.POLineAmount            IS NULL))
    AND (mt.CostCode                = tt.CostCode                OR (mt.CostCode                IS NULL AND tt.CostCode                IS NULL))
    AND (mt.RequisitionId           = tt.RequisitionId           OR (mt.RequisitionId           IS NULL AND tt.RequisitionId           IS NULL))
    AND (mt.RequisitionLineNumber   = tt.RequisitionLineNumber   OR (mt.RequisitionLineNumber   IS NULL AND tt.RequisitionLineNumber   IS NULL))
    AND (mt.Vendor                  = tt.Vendor                  OR (mt.Vendor                  IS NULL AND tt.Vendor                  IS NULL))
    AND (mt.ExchangeName            = tt.ExchangeName            OR (mt.ExchangeName            IS NULL AND tt.ExchangeName            IS NULL))
    AND (mt.COECurrentProjectStatus = tt.COECurrentProjectStatus OR (mt.COECurrentProjectStatus IS NULL AND tt.COECurrentProjectStatus IS NULL))
    AND (mt.ReadyForService         = tt.ReadyForService         OR (mt.ReadyForService         IS NULL AND tt.ReadyForService         IS NULL))
    AND (mt.MaterialSpecialist      = tt.MaterialSpecialist      OR (mt.MaterialSpecialist      IS NULL AND tt.MaterialSpecialist      IS NULL))
    AND (mt.QuantityReceived        = tt.QuantityReceived        OR (mt.QuantityReceived        IS NULL AND tt.QuantityReceived        IS NULL))
    AND (mt.DateReceived            = tt.DateReceived            OR (mt.DateReceived            IS NULL AND tt.DateReceived            IS NULL))
    AND (mt.ReceiverId              = tt.ReceiverId              OR (mt.ReceiverId              IS NULL AND tt.ReceiverId              IS NULL))
    AND (mt.ScheduledShipDate       = tt.ScheduledShipDate       OR (mt.ScheduledShipDate       IS NULL AND tt.ScheduledShipDate       IS NULL))
    AND (mt.CalloutDetails          = tt.CalloutDetails          OR (mt.CalloutDetails          IS NULL AND tt.CalloutDetails          IS NULL))
    AND (mt.ProjectType             = tt.ProjectType             OR (mt.ProjectType             IS NULL AND tt.ProjectType             IS NULL))
    AND (mt.RecordStatus            = tt.RecordStatus            OR (mt.RecordStatus            IS NULL AND tt.RecordStatus            IS NULL))
    AND (mt.MaterialComments        = tt.MaterialComments        OR (mt.MaterialComments        IS NULL AND tt.MaterialComments        IS NULL))
    AND (mt.SchedulerComments       = tt.SchedulerComments       OR (mt.SchedulerComments       IS NULL AND tt.SchedulerComments       IS NULL))
WHERE mt.State                     IS NULL
    AND mt.ProjectNumber           IS NULL
    AND mt.SubProjectNumber        IS NULL
    AND mt.PONumber                IS NULL
    AND mt.POLineNumber            IS NULL
    AND mt.IMLineNumber            IS NULL
    AND mt.POStatus                IS NULL
    AND mt.BlanketRelease          IS NULL
    AND mt.PODateIssued            IS NULL
    AND mt.DateNeeded              IS NULL
    AND mt.POInvoiceStatus         IS NULL
    AND mt.ItemCode                IS NULL
    AND mt.ItemDesc                IS NULL
    AND mt.QuantityOrdered         IS NULL
    AND mt.ShipToLocation          IS NULL
    AND mt.DeliverToLocation       IS NULL
    AND mt.TraceNumber             IS NULL
    AND mt.BOL                     IS NULL
    AND mt.PackSlipNumber          IS NULL
    AND mt.POTotalAmount           IS NULL
    AND mt.POLineAmount            IS NULL
    AND mt.CostCode                IS NULL
    AND mt.RequisitionId           IS NULL
    AND mt.RequisitionLineNumber   IS NULL
    AND mt.Vendor                  IS NULL
    AND mt.ExchangeName            IS NULL
    AND mt.COECurrentProjectStatus IS NULL
    AND mt.ReadyForService         IS NULL
    AND mt.MaterialSpecialist      IS NULL
    AND mt.QuantityReceived        IS NULL
    AND mt.DateReceived            IS NULL
    AND mt.ReceiverId              IS NULL
    AND mt.ScheduledShipDate       IS NULL
    AND mt.CalloutDetails          IS NULL
    AND mt.ProjectType             IS NULL
    AND mt.RecordStatus            IS NULL
    AND mt.MaterialComments        IS NULL
    AND mt.SchedulerComments       IS NULL;

INSERT INTO TestTable (State,ProjectNumber,SubProjectNumber,PONumber,POLineNumber,IMLineNumber,POStatus,BlanketRelease,PODateIssued,DateNeeded,
    POInvoiceStatus,ItemCode,ItemDesc,QuantityOrdered,ShipToLocation,DeliverToLocation,TraceNumber,BOL,PackSlipNumber,POTotalAmount,
    POLineAmount,CostCode,RequisitionId,RequisitionLineNumber,Vendor,ExchangeName,COECurrentProjectStatus,ReadyForService,MaterialSpecialist,
    QuantityReceived,DateReceived,ReceiverId,ScheduledShipDate,CalloutDetails,ProjectType,RecordStatus,MaterialComments,SchedulerComments)
SELECT mt.State,mt.ProjectNumber,mt.SubProjectNumber,mt.PONumber,mt.POLineNumber,mt.IMLineNumber,mt.POStatus,mt.BlanketRelease,mt.PODateIssued,mt.DateNeeded,
    mt.POInvoiceStatus,mt.ItemCode,mt.ItemDesc,mt.QuantityOrdered,mt.ShipToLocation,mt.DeliverToLocation,mt.TraceNumber,mt.BOL,mt.PackSlipNumber,mt.POTotalAmount,
    mt.POLineAmount,mt.CostCode,mt.RequisitionId,mt.RequisitionLineNumber,mt.Vendor,mt.ExchangeName,mt.COECurrentProjectStatus,mt.ReadyForService,mt.MaterialSpecialist,
    mt.QuantityReceived,mt.DateReceived,mt.ReceiverId,mt.ScheduledShipDate,mt.CalloutDetails,mt.ProjectType,mt.RecordStatus,mt.MaterialComments,mt.SchedulerComments
FROM TestingTable tt
RIGHT JOIN MaterialTracking mt
    ON  (mt.State                   = tt.State                   OR (mt.State                   IS NULL AND tt.State                   IS NULL))
    AND (mt.ProjectNumber           = tt.ProjectNumber           OR (mt.ProjectNumber           IS NULL AND tt.ProjectNumber           IS NULL))
    AND (mt.SubProjectNumber        = tt.SubProjectNumber        OR (mt.SubProjectNumber        IS NULL AND tt.SubProjectNumber        IS NULL))
    AND (mt.PONumber                = tt.PONumber                OR (mt.PONumber                IS NULL AND tt.PONumber                IS NULL))
    AND (mt.POLineNumber            = tt.POLineNumber            OR (mt.POLineNumber            IS NULL AND tt.POLineNumber            IS NULL))
    AND (mt.IMLineNumber            = tt.IMLineNumber            OR (mt.IMLineNumber            IS NULL AND tt.IMLineNumber            IS NULL))
    AND (mt.POStatus                = tt.POStatus                OR (mt.POStatus                IS NULL AND tt.POStatus                IS NULL))
    AND (mt.BlanketRelease          = tt.BlanketRelease          OR (mt.BlanketRelease          IS NULL AND tt.BlanketRelease          IS NULL))
    AND (mt.PODateIssued            = tt.PODateIssued            OR (mt.PODateIssued            IS NULL AND tt.PODateIssued            IS NULL))
    AND (mt.DateNeeded              = tt.DateNeeded              OR (mt.DateNeeded              IS NULL AND tt.DateNeeded              IS NULL))
    AND (mt.POInvoiceStatus         = tt.POInvoiceStatus         OR (mt.POInvoiceStatus         IS NULL AND tt.POInvoiceStatus         IS NULL))
    AND (mt.ItemCode                = tt.ItemCode                OR (mt.ItemCode                IS NULL AND tt.ItemCode                IS NULL))
    AND (mt.ItemDesc                = tt.ItemDesc                OR (mt.ItemDesc                IS NULL AND tt.ItemDesc                IS NULL))
    AND (mt.QuantityOrdered         = tt.QuantityOrdered         OR (mt.QuantityOrdered         IS NULL AND tt.QuantityOrdered         IS NULL))
    AND (mt.ShipToLocation          = tt.ShipToLocation          OR (mt.ShipToLocation          IS NULL AND tt.ShipToLocation          IS NULL))
    AND (mt.DeliverToLocation       = tt.DeliverToLocation       OR (mt.DeliverToLocation       IS NULL AND tt.DeliverToLocation       IS NULL))
    AND (mt.TraceNumber             = tt.TraceNumber             OR (mt.TraceNumber             IS NULL AND tt.TraceNumber             IS NULL))
    AND (mt.BOL                     = tt.BOL                     OR (mt.BOL                     IS NULL AND tt.BOL                     IS NULL))
    AND (mt.PackSlipNumber          = tt.PackSlipNumber          OR (mt.PackSlipNumber          IS NULL AND tt.PackSlipNumber          IS NULL))
    AND (mt.POTotalAmount           = tt.POTotalAmount           OR (mt.POTotalAmount           IS NULL AND tt.POTotalAmount           IS NULL))
    AND (mt.POLineAmount            = tt.POLineAmount            OR (mt.POLineAmount            IS NULL AND tt.POLineAmount            IS NULL))
    AND (mt.CostCode                = tt.CostCode                OR (mt.CostCode                IS NULL AND tt.CostCode                IS NULL))
    AND (mt.RequisitionId           = tt.RequisitionId           OR (mt.RequisitionId           IS NULL AND tt.RequisitionId           IS NULL))
    AND (mt.RequisitionLineNumber   = tt.RequisitionLineNumber   OR (mt.RequisitionLineNumber   IS NULL AND tt.RequisitionLineNumber   IS NULL))
    AND (mt.Vendor                  = tt.Vendor                  OR (mt.Vendor                  IS NULL AND tt.Vendor                  IS NULL))
    AND (mt.ExchangeName            = tt.ExchangeName            OR (mt.ExchangeName            IS NULL AND tt.ExchangeName            IS NULL))
    AND (mt.COECurrentProjectStatus = tt.COECurrentProjectStatus OR (mt.COECurrentProjectStatus IS NULL AND tt.COECurrentProjectStatus IS NULL))
    AND (mt.ReadyForService         = tt.ReadyForService         OR (mt.ReadyForService         IS NULL AND tt.ReadyForService         IS NULL))
    AND (mt.MaterialSpecialist      = tt.MaterialSpecialist      OR (mt.MaterialSpecialist      IS NULL AND tt.MaterialSpecialist      IS NULL))
    AND (mt.QuantityReceived        = tt.QuantityReceived        OR (mt.QuantityReceived        IS NULL AND tt.QuantityReceived        IS NULL))
    AND (mt.DateReceived            = tt.DateReceived            OR (mt.DateReceived            IS NULL AND tt.DateReceived            IS NULL))
    AND (mt.ReceiverId              = tt.ReceiverId              OR (mt.ReceiverId              IS NULL AND tt.ReceiverId              IS NULL))
    AND (mt.ScheduledShipDate       = tt.ScheduledShipDate       OR (mt.ScheduledShipDate       IS NULL AND tt.ScheduledShipDate       IS NULL))
    AND (mt.CalloutDetails          = tt.CalloutDetails          OR (mt.CalloutDetails          IS NULL AND tt.CalloutDetails          IS NULL))
    AND (mt.ProjectType             = tt.ProjectType             OR (mt.ProjectType             IS NULL AND tt.ProjectType             IS NULL))
    AND (mt.RecordStatus            = tt.RecordStatus            OR (mt.RecordStatus            IS NULL AND tt.RecordStatus            IS NULL))
    AND (mt.MaterialComments        = tt.MaterialComments        OR (mt.MaterialComments        IS NULL AND tt.MaterialComments        IS NULL))
    AND (mt.SchedulerComments       = tt.SchedulerComments       OR (mt.SchedulerComments       IS NULL AND tt.SchedulerComments       IS NULL))
WHERE tt.State                     IS NULL
    AND tt.ProjectNumber           IS NULL
    AND tt.SubProjectNumber        IS NULL
    AND tt.PONumber                IS NULL
    AND tt.POLineNumber            IS NULL
    AND tt.IMLineNumber            IS NULL
    AND tt.POStatus                IS NULL
    AND tt.BlanketRelease          IS NULL
    AND tt.PODateIssued            IS NULL
    AND tt.DateNeeded              IS NULL
    AND tt.POInvoiceStatus         IS NULL
    AND tt.ItemCode                IS NULL
    AND tt.ItemDesc                IS NULL
    AND tt.QuantityOrdered         IS NULL
    AND tt.ShipToLocation          IS NULL
    AND tt.DeliverToLocation       IS NULL
    AND tt.TraceNumber             IS NULL
    AND tt.BOL                     IS NULL
    AND tt.PackSlipNumber          IS NULL
    AND tt.POTotalAmount           IS NULL
    AND tt.POLineAmount            IS NULL
    AND tt.CostCode                IS NULL
    AND tt.RequisitionId           IS NULL
    AND tt.RequisitionLineNumber   IS NULL
    AND tt.Vendor                  IS NULL
    AND tt.ExchangeName            IS NULL
    AND tt.COECurrentProjectStatus IS NULL
    AND tt.ReadyForService         IS NULL
    AND tt.MaterialSpecialist      IS NULL
    AND tt.QuantityReceived        IS NULL
    AND tt.DateReceived            IS NULL
    AND tt.ReceiverId              IS NULL
    AND tt.ScheduledShipDate       IS NULL
    AND tt.CalloutDetails          IS NULL
    AND tt.ProjectType             IS NULL
    AND tt.RecordStatus            IS NULL
    AND tt.MaterialComments        IS NULL
    AND tt.SchedulerComments       IS NULL;

COMMIT TRANSACTION MAIN;
```

Note that if you have a legitimate record where all 38 fields are NULL, it *will* be deleted and will *not* be copied over with this method.

If you want to try a MERGE, you can use the JOIN logic from the last statements.  The `HOLDLOCK` locking hint is important because it mitigates nearly all the common (if common is even the right word) problems people experience with the statement.

```
MEREGE INTO TestTable WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target
USING MaterialTracking AS source
    ON  (source.State                   = target.State                   OR (source.State                   IS NULL AND target.State                   IS NULL))
    AND (source.ProjectNumber           = target.ProjectNumber           OR (source.ProjectNumber           IS NULL AND target.ProjectNumber           IS NULL))
    AND (source.SubProjectNumber        = target.SubProjectNumber        OR (source.SubProjectNumber        IS NULL AND target.SubProjectNumber        IS NULL))
    AND (source.PONumber                = target.PONumber                OR (source.PONumber                IS NULL AND target.PONumber                IS NULL))
    AND (source.POLineNumber            = target.POLineNumber            OR (source.POLineNumber            IS NULL AND target.POLineNumber            IS NULL))
    AND (source.IMLineNumber            = target.IMLineNumber            OR (source.IMLineNumber            IS NULL AND target.IMLineNumber            IS NULL))
    AND (source.POStatus                = target.POStatus                OR (source.POStatus                IS NULL AND target.POStatus                IS NULL))
    AND (source.BlanketRelease          = target.BlanketRelease          OR (source.BlanketRelease          IS NULL AND target.BlanketRelease          IS NULL))
    AND (source.PODateIssued            = target.PODateIssued            OR (source.PODateIssued            IS NULL AND target.PODateIssued            IS NULL))
    AND (source.DateNeeded              = target.DateNeeded              OR (source.DateNeeded              IS NULL AND target.DateNeeded              IS NULL))
    AND (source.POInvoiceStatus         = target.POInvoiceStatus         OR (source.POInvoiceStatus         IS NULL AND target.POInvoiceStatus         IS NULL))
    AND (source.ItemCode                = target.ItemCode                OR (source.ItemCode                IS NULL AND target.ItemCode                IS NULL))
    AND (source.ItemDesc                = target.ItemDesc                OR (source.ItemDesc                IS NULL AND target.ItemDesc                IS NULL))
    AND (source.QuantityOrdered         = target.QuantityOrdered         OR (source.QuantityOrdered         IS NULL AND target.QuantityOrdered         IS NULL))
    AND (source.ShipToLocation          = target.ShipToLocation          OR (source.ShipToLocation          IS NULL AND target.ShipToLocation          IS NULL))
    AND (source.DeliverToLocation       = target.DeliverToLocation       OR (source.DeliverToLocation       IS NULL AND target.DeliverToLocation       IS NULL))
    AND (source.TraceNumber             = target.TraceNumber             OR (source.TraceNumber             IS NULL AND target.TraceNumber             IS NULL))
    AND (source.BOL                     = target.BOL                     OR (source.BOL                     IS NULL AND target.BOL                     IS NULL))
    AND (source.PackSlipNumber          = target.PackSlipNumber          OR (source.PackSlipNumber          IS NULL AND target.PackSlipNumber          IS NULL))
    AND (source.POTotalAmount           = target.POTotalAmount           OR (source.POTotalAmount           IS NULL AND target.POTotalAmount           IS NULL))
    AND (source.POLineAmount            = target.POLineAmount            OR (source.POLineAmount            IS NULL AND target.POLineAmount            IS NULL))
    AND (source.CostCode                = target.CostCode                OR (source.CostCode                IS NULL AND target.CostCode                IS NULL))
    AND (source.RequisitionId           = target.RequisitionId           OR (source.RequisitionId           IS NULL AND target.RequisitionId           IS NULL))
    AND (source.RequisitionLineNumber   = target.RequisitionLineNumber   OR (source.RequisitionLineNumber   IS NULL AND target.RequisitionLineNumber   IS NULL))
    AND (source.Vendor                  = target.Vendor                  OR (source.Vendor                  IS NULL AND target.Vendor                  IS NULL))
    AND (source.ExchangeName            = target.ExchangeName            OR (source.ExchangeName            IS NULL AND target.ExchangeName            IS NULL))
    AND (source.COECurrentProjectStatus = target.COECurrentProjectStatus OR (source.COECurrentProjectStatus IS NULL AND target.COECurrentProjectStatus IS NULL))
    AND (source.ReadyForService         = target.ReadyForService         OR (source.ReadyForService         IS NULL AND target.ReadyForService         IS NULL))
    AND (source.MaterialSpecialist      = target.MaterialSpecialist      OR (source.MaterialSpecialist      IS NULL AND target.MaterialSpecialist      IS NULL))
    AND (source.QuantityReceived        = target.QuantityReceived        OR (source.QuantityReceived        IS NULL AND target.QuantityReceived        IS NULL))
    AND (source.DateReceived            = target.DateReceived            OR (source.DateReceived            IS NULL AND target.DateReceived            IS NULL))
    AND (source.ReceiverId              = target.ReceiverId              OR (source.ReceiverId              IS NULL AND target.ReceiverId              IS NULL))
    AND (source.ScheduledShipDate       = target.ScheduledShipDate       OR (source.ScheduledShipDate       IS NULL AND target.ScheduledShipDate       IS NULL))
    AND (source.CalloutDetails          = target.CalloutDetails          OR (source.CalloutDetails          IS NULL AND target.CalloutDetails          IS NULL))
    AND (source.ProjectType             = target.ProjectType             OR (source.ProjectType             IS NULL AND target.ProjectType             IS NULL))
    AND (source.RecordStatus            = target.RecordStatus            OR (source.RecordStatus            IS NULL AND target.RecordStatus            IS NULL))
    AND (source.MaterialComments        = target.MaterialComments        OR (source.MaterialComments        IS NULL AND target.MaterialComments        IS NULL))
    AND (source.SchedulerComments       = target.SchedulerComments       OR (source.SchedulerComments       IS NULL AND target.SchedulerComments       IS NULL))
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (State,ProjectNumber,SubProjectNumber,PONumber,POLineNumber,IMLineNumber,POStatus,BlanketRelease,PODateIssued,DateNeeded,
        POInvoiceStatus,ItemCode,ItemDesc,QuantityOrdered,ShipToLocation,DeliverToLocation,TraceNumber,BOL,PackSlipNumber,POTotalAmount,
        POLineAmount,CostCode,RequisitionId,RequisitionLineNumber,Vendor,ExchangeName,COECurrentProjectStatus,ReadyForService,MaterialSpecialist,
        QuantityReceived,DateReceived,ReceiverId,ScheduledShipDate,CalloutDetails,ProjectType,RecordStatus,MaterialComments,SchedulerComments)
VALUES (source.State,source.ProjectNumber,source.SubProjectNumber,source.PONumber,source.POLineNumber,source.IMLineNumber,source.POStatus,source.BlanketRelease,
        source.PODateIssued,source.DateNeeded,source.POInvoiceStatus,source.ItemCode,source.ItemDesc,source.QuantityOrdered,source.ShipToLocation,
        source.DeliverToLocation,source.TraceNumber,source.BOL,source.PackSlipNumber,source.POTotalAmount,source.POLineAmount,source.CostCode,
        source.RequisitionId,source.RequisitionLineNumber,source.Vendor,source.ExchangeName,source.COECurrentProjectStatus,source.ReadyForService,
        source.MaterialSpecialist,source.QuantityReceived,source.DateReceived,source.ReceiverId,source.ScheduledShipDate,source.CalloutDetails,
        source.ProjectType,source.RecordStatus,source.MaterialComments,source.SchedulerComments)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
    DELETE;
```

This should work, but I'm not a huge fan of it here for reasons I've already mentioned.  Again, you're likely to run into problems if you have duplicates or valid records that are all NULL values.

Also, since someone tried to edit my answer to ask, I'm not a fan of logic like `ISNULL(Target.SubProjectNumber,'NULL') = ISNULL(Source.SubProjectNumber,'NULL')`.  Primarily, it's because it executes two functions for every field you join or compare with.  That means there's some additional overhead, but, much worse, *you remove the the ability of the database engine to use an index*.  There's also the problem that you may have legitimate values for whatever value you decide to coalesce/isnull to.  It's much better in the long run to use `(source.SubProjectNumber = target.SubProjectNumber OR (source.SubProjectNumber IS NULL AND target.SubProjectNumber IS NULL))`.  It really isn't that difficult if you have a nice text editor that support column mode.

Answer (score 1):

This is just messed up

1. Insert from B what is not already in A
2. Delete from A what is not in B

Uh, that would be exactly B

3. Update A with rows in B that are different from A in only a couple
   of columns

As for *most* columns - define most
And now A is exactly B so this would be zero anyway

My advice is have a plan.
3.  As the last step is flawed

You don't need to plan with 100 columns
Lets pretend 4 and the first two are the match
And all are not nullable

First delete.  Less rows is less rows to compare.  It may open up pages for the insert (less page splits).

```
delete b 
from b 
 left join a 
   on a.col1 = b.col1 
  and a.col2 = b.col2 
where a.col1 is null
```

next gets a little trickier as with a merge you would update even all columns are the same and want to keep traffic off of b

but if most matches will be updates then use a merge

do update before insert as why deal with more rows than have to

```
update b 
   set b.col3 = a.col3, b.col4 = a.col4
  from b 
  join a 
    on a.col1 = b.col1 
   and a.col2 = b.col2 
   and (a.col3 <> b.col3 or a.col4 <> b.col4)
```

now insert

```
insert into b (col1, col2, col3, col3) 
select col1, col2, col3, col3 
from a 
left join b 
    on a.col1 = b.col1 
   and a.col2 = b.col2 
where b.col1 is null
```

Comment: I agree it will end up as A = B. However there are user in the table locking rows so I'm not able to just truncate and repopulate. That's why I'm going to all the trouble of comparing and then Insert, Update or Delete

Comment: @Mike Then put that in the question.  Right now it reads like you don't really have a master plan.  And there is not purpose to listing out all the columns.   People don't want to read all that.   You could easily represent this with 4 columns.

Answer (score 1):

I still wouldn't do it this way but everyone keeps commenting how much they love merge so here is an answer with that way for you just so you can make your own decision because no one else is writing it for you.

```
MERGE INTO TableA as target
USING (SELECT
            ID
            ,Col1
            ,Col2
            ,Col3
        FROM
            TableB
        ) AS source
        ON (t.ID = s.ID) --change to the relationship

WHEN MATCHED AND (target.Col1 <> source.Col1
             OR target.Col2 <> source.Col2
             OR ISNULL(target.Col3,'Null') <> ISNULL(source.Col3,'NULL'))
     THEN
    UPDATE
       SET Col1 = source.Col1
          ,Col2 = source.Col2

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
--Insert Records That Do Not In Target Table
    INSERT (Id,col1,col2,col3,...) --note this is the target table
    VALUES (Id,col2,col2,col3) --ehese are source column names

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN

    DELETE
    --you could also choose to update a field in target as well

--Don't have to necessarily use output but statement must end with ;
OUTPUT $action, Inserted.*, Deleted.*;
```

Note you can also add conditions to some of the WHEN MATCHED or WHEN NOT MATCHED statements to further limit what you will want to do.

here is an example of that

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND source.col1 <> 'BAD' THEN
--Insert Records That Do Not In Target Table
    INSERT (Id,col1,col2,col3,...)
    VALUES (Id,col2,col2,col3)
```

Again when comparing your rows it will be important that you consider how to handle the comparison of null values.

Looking at your recent edit to your question I am sure both of these answers will change tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than comparing each and every column in some giant where clause, you can create what I would call "virtual keys" which would make comparing the data a lot easier. In fact, you can create 2 keys, one for "all columns" and one for "most columns" based on your requirements.

To do this (and this is a very simple example probably not suitable for production):

```
select 
  a.field1, 
  a.field2, --etc.
  hashbytes('sha2_256', concat(a.field1, '|', a.field2)) as most_col_hash,
  hashbytes('sha2_256', concat(a.field1, '|', a.field2, '|', a.field3)) /*...etc. */ as all_col_hash
into #a_hashed
from table_a
```

etc.

Now you can use all_col_hash in both temp tables to determine which rows have any differences at all, and you can use some_col_hash to determine which rows differ for the columns you used to generate the hash.

You'll want to check for temp table existence at the beginning of the script (and drop if they exist).

You should also use create table statements rather than select into, I just wanted to show the usage of hashbytes here.

Also I think it goes without saying that you should probably be using some kind of identity field or primary key.

Edit: some caveats - limit is 8000 bytes on the input string. Also, hashes are CASE SENSITIVE. If you expect case insensitivity then you have to normalize your input or you will end up with rows which are technically equivalent (if your collation is case insensitive) yet have different hashes.

Comment: Eric -- why add pipes to the hash? Also, using hashbytes is super useful for some things, but one thing to watch out for, especially in the suggested way, is that it is limited to 4,000 characters.

Comment: Because if you don't delimit the columns, it's possible to have rows with different column values concatenate to an identical string. For example, concat('explore','ram') is equivalent to concat('explorer','am'), and these two identical strings would have the same hash, even though they have different values.

Comment: The limit is 8000 bytes of input, by the way. For non-unicode (eg varchar) that's 8000 characters. That's nearly 8mb per row. Your point is still valid - you should check the maximum size of the columns you are hashing and when added together this should be less than 8000. If you find that it's possible to overflow that limit, you can split the columns into groups as necessary, and either concatenate the hashes or rehash them together.

Comment: Eric -- thanks for the explanation on the reason to use the delimiter. Makes total sense.

Answer (score -3):

Seems my "do not user `MERGE`" Statement is unpopular.  I stand by my statement I have seen improvement in my own ETL by removing it.  It essentially does the same thing as below. I have also found when handling more than a dozen or so rows that troubleshooting each statement independently to be more efficient than working through a merge.

use 3 statements updating records first.

So Find records that are in both tables but different.  Make sure you handle the `NULL` values in fields when comparing as not every datatype will nicely compare a null to a null for you.

```
UPDATE A
    SET Col1 = b.Col1
       ,Col2 = b.Col2
       ,Col3 = c.Col3
       ...
FROM
    TableA a
    INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON a.PrimaryKey = b.PrimaryKey -- or whatever the relatnioship is
WHERE
    a.Col1 <> b.Col1
    OR a.Col2 <> b.Col2
    OR ISNULL(a.Col3,'DefaultValue') <> ISNULL(b.Col3,'DefaultValue')
    OR ...
```

Then find the records not in `A` that are in `B` and `insert`

```
INSERT INTO TableA (Col1,Col2,Col3,...)
SELECT
    Col1
    ,Col2
    ,Col3
    ,...
FROM
    TableB b
    LEFT JOIN TableA a
    ON b.PrimaryKey = a.PrimaryKey
WHERE
    a.PrimaryKey IS NULL
```

Then go `delete` the records from `a` that are not in `b`

```
DELETE a
FROM
    TableA a
    LEFT JOIN TableB b
    ON a.PrimaryKey = b.PrimaryKey
WHERE
    b.PrimaryKey IS NULL
```

Be sure to make sure the relationship part of the `join` has the right columns

For more on why not to use merge do a internet search here is one article of all of the bugs on mssqltips.com: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

funny that this gets a down votes because it is unpopular, yet it is valid and in some database platforms your only choice.  This has been the one of the primary methods to merge records for decades now.

Comment: `DO NOT USE MERGE` - are you serious?

Comment: The biggest problem here is there is no primary key that is in both tables. The `ID` is just an identity that is create for each table, but not for both.

Comment: You have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: @RandyMinder are you talking about me having now idea?  how so?

Comment: @Mike whatever technique you use you will have to be able to relate the information between the tables.  I realize their primarykeys will not likely be the same but what information contained within the tables will signify to you that it is the same record?

Comment: @Matt - Yes you. The MERGE statement is totally solid and performant. I'm using it to keep almost 300 tables updated, every five minutes, on a reporting server.

Comment: I got rid of it and changed to the structure about for millions and millions of rows and my performance is way way better!  So post an answer with it and show him how to do it and then discuss why it is so solid as you say it is and let him choose but no need to attach in a ridiculous manner especially when I posted supporting evidence of my claim

Comment: @Mike and @Matt -- just to help set things straight here -- a statement like `DO NOT USE MERGE` is a bit draconian. There are many very useful applications for it. However, there are some drawbacks, which are very well documented by Microsoft and others. For instance, there are some special considerations when dealing with triggers, weirdness with tables that have filtered indexes, etc. I too have seen pickup gains for using old-school merge, but still find `merge` to be very useful.

Comment: @Yobik that's fair it may have been a little draconian, Personally switching from the old-school merge I have seen way more than a 10 fold performance gain, probably in part to switching to some temp tables for some things too, but personally if their are draw backs why implement it.  I do find the downvotes for a valid method are ridiculous but hey its a community and people can do what they want.